# What css style should I use to display in-line error messages in my WebPart?

Tags: css, sharepoint, web-parts

I'm writing a custom web part that is intended to be hosted in SharePoint. The web part has a button, which when pressed performs an action. This action may or may not succeed. If it fails, I'd like to notify the user by displaying a <span> below the button with an error message.

To make this message stand out, I'd like to highlight it in a different colour or font. I'd like to reuse any existing error CSS style if at all possible. Does SharePoint define such a CSS style? If not, what's the best approach for displaying in-line error messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, silly me, it was right here on:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd586616(v=office.11).aspx
The magic CSS style is `.ms-error`, which as Madhur mentioned is colored red.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint by default uses red colored text to display error messages. You can use the same.

I am not sure if there is any re-useable CSS class exposed by sharepoint for that purpose.

You can check out all the exposed styles here:

http://www.heathersolomon.com/content/sp07cssreference.htm

Comment: Thanks, this is what I have now. I looked at the page you referred to but couldn't find a style. I'll keep googling, but I was hoping this would be a well-known thing.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. 
Check http://jsfiddle.net/AbdK7/

Comment: Hey, thanks for the link to jsfiddle -- it looks like a sweet tool for testing CSS/JScript. Alas, it doesn't answer my question, which is: is there a CSS class to be used in a SharePoint web part to indicate an error. I've just discovered that the CSS class "ms-error" is the right one to use.

Comment: I misunderstood the question. Anyway you can use it when needed :-)